# Why Apache doesn't restart in OSX for making Apache Server run in MAMP

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

I am receiving the following error:

```
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.108 for ServerName
```

Do you know what I should do ? I was following this tutorial: [enter link description here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the warning, edit the configuration file (**/opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf**) and set the server name appropriately. For personal use, localhost is sufficient.

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP

Comment: I did this however yet the apache server light doesn't go green however this error is omitted. I also did what you told in the other post but it was unsuccessful!